# A filter with the certain values for a datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using [datatables](http://datatables.net/). It displays people. Some people can, of course, be older then, let's say, 18. What I want to do is to add a custom filter to it so that I'll be able to filter people those are older than 18. Note this won't be sorting (sorting by age), it should be exactly a filter  having values "less or equal to 18" and "older than 18" -- a drop down list or radio buttons.

I didn't find something at datatables' forum which would help me.

How do I do it?

Note that the table retrieves data from a server.

Comment: Show us your code to make the datatable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DataTables custom filtering (range filtering) plug-in](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html) example can help customize filtering of people's age.

Comment: I want predefined variables, I don't want to have to enter them every time.

Comment: An example has been added on http://jsfiddle.net/7GyQt/4/. There's a drop down list that controls display in the data table

Comment: but it's not working: when I change the value in drop down, nothing happens.

Comment: My apologies. I hadn't saved my work on that revision. Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/zedfoxus/7GyQt/11/. I tested it on IE9 and latest versions of Chrome and Firefox

Comment: it looks good. will it work for me since I retrieve data from a server? what do I have to change there then?

Comment: would you mind explaining in a nutshell what `$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push` does? it looks tricky.

Comment: If you are building an HTML table using server-side processing, the code will work fine, although I haven't tested it out. DataTables applies its features after the HTML document is ready. The [afnFiltering](http://www.datatables.net/development/filtering) applies custom filtering. The push() method takes your customized filtering code and applies it. There's a [nice discussion](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/7207/.fn.datatableext.afnfiltering.push-what-is-this/p1) about afnFiltering also